# ImportError when separating test files from project files

Tags: python, importerror

I'm attempting to implement a Python project with a src layout structure.  Essentially putting unit tests in a `test` directory and project files in a `src` directory.

I'm getting an import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_project\tests\test_mod1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src import mod1 as m1
ImportError: cannot import name 'mod1' from 'src' (unknown location)
```

I'm looking to understand why I am getting this error and how to fix it.

I've included the code and file structure below.  I know the code doesn't implement an actual unit test (planning to do that after getting this to work).  Also, I would like to do this with out having to specify absolute paths.  Online material seem to indicate this should work, but obviously I've made a mistake somewhere.

Here is the project structure:

```
test_project/
│
├── src/
│   └── __init__.py
│   └── mod1.py
└── tests/
    └── __init__.py
    └── test_mod1.py
```

The `__init__.py` files are empty.

mod1.py:

```
def add(x,y):
    return x + y
```

test_mod1.py:

```
from src import mod1 as m1

x,y = 3,4
print(m1.add(x,y))
```

Comment: I'm having issues getting the file structure to look right.  To clarify, __init__.py and mod1.py are under src, and __init__.py and test_mod1.py are under tests

Comment: from ..src import mod1 as m1

x, y = 3, 4
print(m1.add(x, y))
Relative Imports with '__package__' :
Modify 'test_mod1.py' to use relative imports based on the package name:

Comment: @StillLearning You were using quote formatting when you should've been using [code formatting](/editing-help#code) (or pre-formatting). I fixed it for you :)

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [Python import src modules when running tests](/q/4761041/4518341). Note that the different answers have a variety of solutions.

Comment: A simple solution here could be to run the tests from `test_project`, or Python won't know how to find `src`. Otherwise I'm pretty sure that's already been answered in other questions in SO.